# PHP and OCI-Lob::read from oracle clob

Tags: php, oracle, clob, oracle-call-interface

I'm having a weird problem with PHP and the OCI-Lob::read method.

We have a page that connects to the database and pulls all the other fields out with no problems.  However, it when it comes to the clobs, only a small portion of the actual data is retrieved.

The code uses:

```
$content= $features[14]->read(2000);
echo $content;
```

And we're getting a tiny section of the field returned (only about **185** out of a total **553** chars).  The really strange thing is that no matter what the length specified is - it still only returns a small section and - the cut off seems to actually be 549 bytes/chars - anything below the length specified as 549 shortens the returned string but anything over 549 makes no difference.

Additionally, we've used the OCI-Lob::load method with exactly the same results where only a portion of the actual contents of the clob field is returned.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem stems from the connect string!

The TNS_ALIAS wasn't properly configured so I hard coded the connect string and then it worked - for some bizarre reason, a minor error in the TNS_ALIAS config allowed some, but not all of the clob data to get pulled through.